# Gradle Project sync failed Android Studio (e.g. editing, debugging) will not work

Tags: android, android-studio

This is the first time i work with Android studio, and i'm facing this problem with says Cradle Project Sync Failed (e.g. editing, debugging) will not work properly.

[image]

Comment: Sure i will keep you posted

Answer (score 0):

Go to

> *Tools--> Android - > Sync Project with gradle*

if it does nt work try

> *File -> Invalidate Cache and Restart*